# Azure Devops Pipeline Trigger on tag and specific Branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I exhausted all the options here and its only Tuesday.

I have a repository with 3 branches:

- development
- staging
- master

I am trying to set the triggers to behave differently based on the branch. What i mean it this:

- development = trigger on everything (commit, pr and tags)
- Staging = Trigger only on tags created on this branch
- Master = Same as staging.

I have the 3 pipelines as follow:

Development branch:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - development
```

Staging Branch:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  tags:
    include:
      - 'v*'
  branches:
    include:
      - staging
    exclude:
      - '*'
```

Master Branch

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  tags:
    include:
      - 'v*'
  branches:
    include:
      - main
    exclude:
      - '*'
```

Everything works just fine when i push a normal commit on development, only development triggers. but if i create a tag on `development` all the pipelines trigger(staging and master). As far as i understand the `Tags` and `Branches` are conditions that as long as one of them is true, they trigger. I dont understand why microsoft is doing it this way if the pipelines resides in different branches but i am looking for a work around this limitations. I thought on excluding the branches but that will go out of control easily.

Any advice or a better solution please?

Thank you so much for any help you can provide me with

Answer (score 0):

From this [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/commit/2bafd668c9a7162cccc445fcecd8acec737d9181#diff-a82eef1106ec0e7c5b5acae82ead037a), it seems you could not let tags filter with branch filters that include file paths.

But considering that includes are processed first, and then excludes are removed from that list.

Therefore, you could try to write clearly the tag as an explicit include and exclude in the triggers part to see whether it could meet your requirement:

New a repo with three empty branches: stage, main, dev

In dev you should write tag include in trigger if you would like it be triggered by tags in dev branch:
for example, 2.yml in dev branch

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
  tags:
    include:
      - v*
```

azure-pipelines.yml in main branch:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - refs/tags/v*
    exclude:
      - dev
      - stage
  tags:
    include:
      - v*
    exclude:
      - dev/*
      - stage/*  
  paths:
    exclude:
      - /*
```

and 1.yml in stage branch:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - stage
      - refs/tags/v*
    exclude:
      - dev
      - main
  tags:
    include:
      - v*
    exclude:
      - dev/*
      - main/* 
  paths:
    exclude:
      - /*
```

Then here are results test from my side:

commits on dev triggers 2.yml pipeline
adding tag v* on dev will triggers 2.yml pipeline

commits on stage doesn't trigger 1.yml pipeline
adding tag v* on dev triggers 1.yml pipeline

commit on main trigger azure-pipelines.yml pipeline
add tag v* on main trigger azure-pipelines.yml pipeline

Please kindly see and try whether it is what you want.

You could also consider the following two methods:

Alternative 1: As your first step, conditionally abort the build as "cancelled" if the branch name is not what you expect. You could see [this](https://github.com/lextm/vstsabort) for more details.

Alternative 2: Add a condition like eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchname'], 'master') or contains(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') to every single step in your pipeline. This is tedious, but simple. You could see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) for more details.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply. I tried your approache but is not working as expected. If on dev branch i create a tag and push it. This will trigger both Staging and Master. As you advice, is better to only have the condition `condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')`. With only this if i push a tag to dev, the stg pipeline will trigger but exits in 1 second.

Comment: Thanks for your telling! I am glad if it could do some help.